# How to use paths with CreateJS

Tags: path, createjs

I'm trying to develop a small game using CreateJS.

I want to draw a path, using this tool: http://tomkrcha.com/?p=3640 and then I need to make an object which will move on this path.

Is this possible? I don't  understand, how can I link an object with a path...

Thanks.

Comment: It might be possible to use the output from DrawScript to feed values into the MotionGuidePlugin. Its not a bad idea to add path parsing in Graphics to the MotionGuidePlugin. Here is the docs on the plugin: www.createjs.com/Docs/TweenJS/classes/MotionGuidePlugin.html

Comment: Thanks, I tried this way, but it doesn't works... The output from DrawScript has another format :(

Comment: I found a demo which is 100% what I need, but it is made with other game engine. Our system has just CreateJS and I can't add another engine, I should to use just CreateJS. Here is the demo: http://labs.hyperandroid.com/static/CAAT-Samples/demos/demo1/path.html